# Angular KendoUI Combobox initial model value

Tags: angularjs, combobox, kendo-ui

I am having trouble two-way data-binding to an object. Here is an example of the setup:

```
<select kendo-combo-box 
        k-data-source="objectList"
        k-placeholder="'Content Type'"
        k-data-text-field="'title'"
        k-filter="'contains'"
        k-ng-model="selectedObject"
        k-on-change="doSomeStuff()"></select>
```

This works fine except if the default value of `selectedValue` is ex:

```
{
  title: 'defaultValue',
  value: someValue 
}
```

I would expect that this would be reflected in the combobox as the selected item. However the combobox is converting the Object to a string and the selected value is [object Object]. On initialization it does not respect the `k-data-text-field` property.

I cannot figure out how to do this and I think that what I'm trying to do should be the expected behaviour. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `k-data-text-field` without also specifying a `k-data-value-field`.

Without this Kendo has no way to determine what the actual value is it should be binding to when calling `.value()` on the widget, so it just does a `.toString()` on the whole object.

**From the [kendo docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#configuration-dataTextField):**

> **Important** When **`dataTextField`** is defined, the **`dataValueField`** option also should be set.

You simply need to add some way for kendo to uniquely identify your object in the list for binding.

`k-data-value-field="'value'"`

Here is an example showing what that might look like:

http://dojo.telerik.com/Ukije

Comment: Okay I feel like a bit of a goon because I could have sworn I had tried that and was not getting the expected result. I added k-data-value-field and it worked. However I also had to add k-auto-bind="false" for it to display the k-data-text-field value instead of displaying the k-data-value-field value.